# How to make some Action dependent on another Action's finish?

Tags: java, swing, action, actionlistener, synchronized

```
Action pasteAction = new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction();

JPopupMenu popMenu = new JPopupMenu();

menuItem = new JMenuItem();
menuItem.addActionListener(pasteAction);
menuItem.addActionListener(searchAction);
menuItem.setText("Paste & Search");
```

`popMenu` menu is shown up; on mouse right click on `JTextField`

`pasteAction` is ready made.

`searchAction` has code to check if `JTextField` is empty or not. If it is not empty, then do search...

The **problem** is that - as I think - the `pasteAction` and `searchAction` are invoked simultaneously. So `searchAction` is invoked no matter `pasteAction` has finished its job. So when `searchAction` is invoked to check `JTextField` content; it founds it empty!

How to make `searchAction` dependent on `pasteAction`'s finish?

Comment: 'The problem is that - as I think' - debugging can tell you exactly if you are correct or not

Comment: @AdamSkywalker  No errors; just problem of simultaneous invoke. OK I will delete "as I think"

Comment: @AdamSkywalker When `JTextField ` has already some text, the `searchAction` detect that `JTextField` is not empty and go for search OK. But when `JTextField` is empty, and click the menuItem, it pasts but not search because it detects it as empty.

Comment: I mean debugging (or logging) can show if they are executed simultaneously or not. If so, add a complex action to guarantee the execution order

Answer (score 3):

One option is to make a generic Action implementation that takes in a list of actions to take in serial. Then loop over that list, calling one at a time.  Now use that new implementation and add it as the action listener.

Answer (score 3):

As it was proposed by AAG:

```
/**
 * Action which allows to execute several actions as one.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CombinedAction extends AbstractAction {

    /** Holds the list of actions. */
    private Action[] actions;

    /**
     * C'tor.
     * 
     * @param someActions actions which must be executed together.
     */
    public CombinedAction(String aName, Action... someActions) {
        super(aName);
        this.actions = someActions;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (final Action a : actions) {
            a.actionPerformed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Action act = new CombinedAction("Paste and Search", pasteAction, searchAction);
menuItem = new JMenuItem(act);
```

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that - as I think - the pasteAction and searchAction are invoked simultaneously.

The Actions are not invoked simultaneously.

All code invoked from a listener executes on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. This is to make sure the code executes single threaded. This is one of the most important concept of Swing so it is important that you read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information to understand this basic concept.

The problem is that the default implementation of the listener code is to invoke the listeners in the reverse order in which the listeners were added. So you could use:

```
menuItem.addActionListener(searchAction);
menuItem.addActionListener(pasteAction);
```

However, the order of listener execution is implementation specific and is not guaranteed in the Java spec. So the better approarch is to use a combined Action.